# Deleting tables on a relational database (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I managed a relational database and I want to delete a table and their sons (reference as a reference value like fk_table_value).

When I'm doing a simple "`DELETE FROM companies WHERE id=4`" I have that error message : "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails".

Here you can see my database map.

[image: database map]

Comment: You have three tables dependant on Companies table. If you delete that company, some entity loses it’s foreign key entity. To say it plasticly, company_division, params_value and schedule_type should not have fk_company_id = 4.

Comment: That's the point, I want to delete each entries related to that company from all those tables.

Comment: The simple answer is that you must first delete any dependent rows in the other three tables.

Comment: You have found an example of what `FOREIGN KEYs` are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    building_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Lets say you have defined two tables like this. So we can see that rooms have a foreign key on buildings and it is set ON DELETE CASCADE. That means that if entity from buildings is deleted all the room with that building_no will be also deleted.

This will also fix your problem.